# getImageData - Web workers - How can I reduce garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, canvas, garbage-collection

I've got a sample web-worker canvas update script running, but I've noticed it stalls every few seconds for about 200ms. The usual loop time is around 15ms.

I'm guessing this is garbage collection - it looks like it from the profiler.

http://codepen.io/SarahC/pen/bgBoMM

I think it is in this function:

```
function nextFrame(){
  timeChart.start();
  workersWorking = workerCount;
  var stripHeight = ~~( h / workerCount );
  for(var i = 0; i < workerCount; i++){
    var localImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, stripHeight * i, w, stripHeight); /// This needs putting in constant memory.... GC takes ages here.
    workers[i].postMessage({imageData: localImageData, YPosition: stripHeight * i, threadNumber: i});
  }
}
```

If it is this bit that's making all the garbage memory, I don't know what I can do to keep using the same area of memory for these blocks of data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Pass the buffer of your imageData instead of the imageData itself.

This way, your buffer is [transferred](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast) (with a *zero-copy* operation), and doesn't pollute main thread's memory anymore.
Otherwise, when you don't transfer it your object is *structured cloned* (just like if you did `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject));`), which means that you computer holds three copies of the same data in memory when you send back from the worker to the main thread.

Note that when being passed in the worker, the imageData's data is not available anymore in the main thread (it will throw an error if i.e you try to putImageData() it).
I unfortunately don't know of a good way to change the buffer of an ImageData, but you can set a buffer at the creation thanks to the [`ImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData#Browser_compatibility) constructor (apparently still not supported in IE...), which will indeed just create a pointer to the arrayBuffer.

So when all this is supported, only the ImageData structure (basically an object `{width:XXX, height:XXX}`) is created instead of an heavy buffer. Everything else is just moved, and doesn't pollute the memory.

```js
let workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerScript.textContent], {
  type: 'application/javascript'
}));

const worker = new Worker(workerURL);
worker.onmessage = e => {
  let buf = e.data,
    arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(buf),
    processedImageData;
  try {
    processedImageData = new ImageData(arr, imageData.width, imageData.height);
  } catch (e) {
    processedImageData = ctx.createImageData(imageData.width, imageData.height);
    processedImageData.data.set(arr);
  }
  // checks that we didn't created an useless buffer in this last step
  // IE will because it doesn't support new ImageData(buf)
  console.log('Does our TypedArray share the same buffer as the one we received ? ',
              arr.buffer === buf);
  console.log('Does our new imageData share the same buffer as the one we received ? ',
              processedImageData.data.buffer === buf);
  // Note that here a check for the original imageData's buffer has no sense
  //       since it has been emptied
  ctx.putImageData(processedImageData, 0, 0);
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 80);
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 150);
// pass it as transferable
worker.postMessage(imageData.data.buffer, [imageData.data.buffer]);
console.log(imageData.data.length, 'now empty')
```

```html
<script type="worker-script" id="workerScript">
 self.onmessage = e => {
  let buf = e.data,
  arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
  console.log('worker received', buf);
  for(let i =0; i<arr.length; i+=4){
   arr[i] = (arr[i] + 128) % 255;
   arr[i+1] = (arr[i+1] + 128) % 255;
   arr[i+2] = (arr[i+2] + 128) % 255;   
   }
  self.postMessage(buf, [buf]);
  // this won't print in stacksnippet's console
  // you have to check your dev tools' one
  console.log('worker now holds', buf.byteLength, 'empty');

  };
</script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And a counter example using structure cloning :

```js
let workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerScript.textContent], {
  type: 'application/javascript'
}));

const worker = new Worker(workerURL);
worker.onmessage = e => {
  let buf = e.data;
  // so our original imageData's arrayBuffer is still available
  imageData.data.set(buf);
  // Here we can check for equality with the first arrayBuffer
  console.log('Is the first bufferArray the same as the one we received ?', imageData.data.buffer === buf);  
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 80);
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 150);
// pass it as transferable
worker.postMessage(imageData.data.buffer);
console.log(imageData.data.length, 'not empty')
```

```html
<script type="worker-script" id="workerScript">
 self.onmessage = e => {
  let buf = e.data,
  arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
  console.log('worker received', buf);
  for(let i =0; i<arr.length; i+=4){
   arr[i] = (arr[i] + 128) % 255;
   arr[i+1] = (arr[i+1] + 128) % 255;
   arr[i+2] = (arr[i+2] + 128) % 255;   
   }
  console.log(arr);
  self.postMessage(buf);
  // this won't print in stacksnippet's console
  // you have to check your dev tools' one
  console.log('worker now holds', buf.byteLength, 'full');
  };
</script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Whoa! .... this is interesting: (imageData.data.buffer, [imageData.data.buffer]) .. that gets it to do a zero copy? Thanks for the example - you wrote that for my post? I'm going to try your example in codepen to understand the ins and outs better.

Comment: @SarahC, yes that's it.

Comment: Am I limited to sending the buffer through in the one call you demo there? Is there a way of sending an object containing other information without having to post another message?  It's tricky to google, and it's 4:10am for me.

Comment: @SarahC no, you can also just pass any object as first argument, as long as the second one holds your arrayBuffer : `worker.postMessage({buffer:imageData.data.buffer, otherKey:'hello'}, [imageData.data.buffer])` should work just fine.

Comment: @SarahC, about your previous and now deleted comment, the last test is just to be sure that the final imageData does hold the same buffer as the one that has been sent back to the worker. Since the first one has lost the memory allocation of his one, we can't do an an equality check on it. But since you reported it still had a length when doing a structured clone, it means the arrayBuffer is now thrice in the memory as stated in my answer (you can do an equality check that will show that the first imageData's arrayBuffer is not the same). I agree my answer may be confusing about it.

Comment: I'd posted before I'd engaged my head. I went back and had a look properly, and realised what was going on - I only glanced originally and though it was comparing the buffer that got "neutered" (as the error message says in Chrome if it's tried to be set) to the one passed back - which was wrong. I realised when I went back that it was comparing the buff before and after creating the new ImageData. I've already had an experiment with the code, and got 15 FPS increase on one of my test programs. Eventually when I've got time, I'll add it to my Magic Eye code. =)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can only reduce the overall GC hits in each JS context by reusing the pixel data arrays, but you can not make a significant change. The problem is the data that is transferred to and from the workers.

When you post data to the worker, the worker has to assign memory to receive that data. It can not say "here is some RAM I am already using please put it in here". Sadly no, a posted message and its contents arrive at the worker's context as a new object every time. And the same applies to the returning data, every message is a new message, with a new referance, assignment and eventual removal.

You can send smallers chunks of data at a time, and that may spread the GC hits out so you don't get the big GC spikes. But memory usage is tied to memory throughput, unless you reduce the throughput you will not reduce the GC load.

You might want to have a look at [sharedArrayBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) as they provide a shared memory resource between Javascript threads. Current support is Chrome (requires flags) and Firefox. But there is a push to get this type of memory managment happening so it may be worth your while trying it out.

SharedArrayBuffers should go a long way to almost eliminating GC hits for this type of application.

#### UPDATE:

In the light of new information you can try using the transferable transfer argument in the worker.postMessage call. See the draft W3C [worker postmessage](https://w3c.github.io/workers/#dom-worker-postmessage) for posting to the worker and [worker global scope postmessage](https://w3c.github.io/workers/#dom-dedicatedworkerglobalscope-postmessage) for returning data from the worker.

The transferable object is defined here [transferable objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects) <strike>which points out that you can only transfer an object once. When the worker receives the object it can not return it as a transferable object (according to the documentation). You will have to create a new typed array from any array you receive if you wish to return it as a transferable.</strike>

What is unclear from the documentation is how this effect memory management within the context of the sender.

#### Update 2

After playing with transferable data I have found that to stop any memory overhead you need to have two copies of the data (in the case of imageData)

The imageData.data property that holds the pixel data can not be used after it has been transfered. You need to either create a new imageData array or copy the data to send to another array and copy it back when returned with the typedArray `set` function.

The following is an example (bits of code not the whole thing) of using transferable data to transfer data to and from a worker while not incurring undue GC overheads. Running code similar on Chrome and checking the timeline shows no GC hits over 0.002ms

```
// one time set up
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 512, 512);
var tData = new Uint8ClampedArray(512 * 512 * 4); 
tData.set(imgData.data);

// repeats from here
worker.sendMessage(tData.buffer, [tData.buffer]);

// In the worker
onmessage(event){
    var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(event.data);
    // process the data
    // return data
    postMessage(event.data,[event.data]);
}

// Back on the main thread
onmessage(event){
    tData = new Uint8ClampedArray(event.data);
    imgData.data.set(tData);
    ctx.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
}
// now you can resend tData as it is a new typedArray referance (to the same data)
```

Comment: I see - thank you for helping me out with so much detail. I'll read up on the shared array buffers and have a go with them.

Comment: array buffers could easily be allocated outside the GC heap, with the JS objects themselves just being pointers. So just sending them around should not cause significant GC pressure. Not to mention that arraybuffers and ImageBitmap are transferable, which this could be made zero-copy. So I'm not convinced that the postMessage is the issue

Comment: @the8472 ArrayBuffers and typedArrays are the best way to move data from one context to the next. But each context is isolated from the the others memory. ArrayBuffers are copied when sent to a worker, it is not just a referance sent. This means that both the sender and the receiver need to allocate the RAM required to hold the array. for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm

Comment: the objects must be copied, but internally they can just contain a pointer into a fixed piece of memory which does not necessarily need copying. This is how blobs work for example. Also *structured clone* is not the same as *transferable* objects in `postMessage`.

Comment: @the8472 Are you saying that when I message an array buffer to a worker the memory it occupied in the original context just disappears (moves to the workers context) and a fresh memory resource is available. Seams to me like a great way to dump memory. Just run a worker the will take all the garbage, let its context and GC handle the mess while the main context has an inexhaustible supply of fresh RAM to play with and no GC overhead.

Comment: Blobs: always, ArrayBuffer: only when you *transfer* it (last argument of `postMessage`)

Comment: I think you misread the docs... What they say is that once they are transfered, you can't transfer it again (implicitely in the same context) since it is not available to the context anymore. But you can transfer it to a worker then from the worker to main then to main to worker... It will never be in the same original arrayBuffer object, but the data actually held by the arrayBuffers and thus the memory used are always the same.

Comment: Ps : you can see in my answer that the data is not held by the worker (you'd have to open your own console to see the logs, stacksnippet's one can't show it)

Comment: About last edit. A little more work and you'll find that you can directly create an imageData object from an arrayBuffer, thus no empty arrayBuffer created. And you'll end up with an answer that just does say the same as the one below...

Comment: @Kaiido ?? how?

Comment: @Kaiido Ok found the `new ImageData(array,width,height)` will try it now

Comment: @Kaiido Tried that and it increased the GC hit from the previous <0.002ms and ~130kb every 10sec to 0.63ms 1mb every 6 secs. The whole point of the exercise is to reduce GC hits. Creating a new object each cycle is not just a few bytes, you need to reuse to avoid GC

Comment: The new ImageData(array) will create a new imageData object without creating a new arrayBuffer (just a pointer). The GC hit should be lowered since in your case you are creating a new arrayBuffer the length of the previous one filled with 0 (here it needs memory allocation) and then fill it with the data -> your data is allocated twice in memory. Still better than thrice of OP but with new ImageData it should be allocated only once, at the creation of the original imageData. For your result, I would suspect either a bug in your code, either one in the UA.

Comment: @Kaiido It is not the data that is the problem it is the ImageData object itself. I created using `new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(event.data),512,512)` so there is not much that can go wrong. @ ~ 8 frames a second over 6 seconds. Use dev tools and see how much memory a empty ImageData array needs to exist and you will see that the 1mb is correct

Comment: Of course the data is a problem ! What you are doing is allocating twice the data in the memory, while the ImageData(array) is allocating a simple object of the form of `{width:XXX, height:XXX data:aPointerToAlreadyUsedMemory}`. You can check that in your version `imgData.data.buffer !== event.data` You **cloned** the data, so allocating it twice in memory. Where an ImageData is loud is in its arrayBuffer (180000 bytes for an 300*150 canvas), not in its structure.

Comment: @Kaiido Just use the devtools timeline. Create One 8bit clamp array. Then create an imageData object from that data on a timed loop. The heap usage climbs at the same rate no mater the size of the array. And to prove that new ImageData does not create a copy of typedArray ` var d= new Uint8ClampedArray(512*512*4); var id=new ImageData(d,512,512); d.fill(255); ctx.putImageData(id,0,0);` Note I set the data after creating the image data object yet the canvas set get white pixels.

Comment: After having performed an allocation Timeline recording against both methods, I stay on my positions. http://pastebin.com/ELRN3jfd

Comment: @Kaiido What are you doing? Why are you creating a new array each loop??? `var d= new Uint8ClampedArray(512*512*4);`

Comment: Because what are you sending to your worker ? OP is doing getImageData at each frame. So if we remove the worker, at each frame you are creating a copy in an Uint8Array. Which is exactly what my tests do test.

Comment: @Kaiido The canvas pixel state matches the state returned by the worker. The OP does not render to the canvas (apart from putImageData) so there is no need to use getImageData once the workers are started as the pixel state is maintained in the buffers that are moved to and from the workers. That is why I said two buffers are needed, one is only used to move data to the canvas, the other maintains state. Both buffers live as long as the app and not affected if workers are closed.