# Avoiding two full copies to update a canvas from WebAssembly?

Tags: canvas, webassembly, typed-arrays, putimagedata, imagedata

In JavaScript I can directly manipulate the pixels of a canvas and refresh them with a single copy:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
pixelTypedArray = imageData.data

modifyPixels(pixelTypedArray)

// refresh canvas with single copy
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
```

But in wasm we must allocate our own `TypedArray` using the wasm memory, and we can then use `imageData.data.set(myTypedArray)` but that seems to just copy the entire contents of the new typed array into the canvas's typed array, which must still be followed by `putImageData`, copying the entire contents a second time.

Is there any way to reassign the canvas's ImageData to our new ImageData so that we can update the canvas with only a single copy using `ctx.putImageData()`?

If not, it seems much of the benefit of using wasm to manipulate the image would be wasted by the inefficient double copy and dual in-memory representation, especially when working with large images and/or continuously updating canvas.

Comment: The ImageData you got is completely detached from the canvas, so calling it "the canvas's ImageData" is a bit misleading.
I'm not into wasm and so I'm not too sure as to how you sahre memory between assemblyscripts and js. Can you *tranfer* it? Is your `myTypedArray` always the same object? You can very well create a new ImageData from an ArrayBuffer quite easily, without the need to `set` anything. So if you can [transfer this ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722068/41732553#41732553), then you can have a single copy (and the internal one(s) of the canvas)

Comment: @Kaiido: Thanks! While the transferring was new to me and doesn't seem to be supported by wasm, what I needed was to create my own ImageData as well as my own TypedArray. I had tried each separately but not both together. (The only vaguely similar examples I could find while teaching myself this stuff were also double-copying.) If you post an answer I will accept it.