# multiple web workers to draw canvas imagedata

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker

I'm postulating ways to greatly increase the drawing of a canvas, particularly larger canvases, like 1920/1080

I'm aware of OffscreenCanvas, but I'm looking for alternatives atm.

I was thinking of using a web worker to generate the image data, postMessage it to the main thread, and keep doign so back again etc., but when I have imagedata greater, or close to, 1920 / 1080, it takes a very long time to send it (like 50+ ms).

So I was thinking of splitting up the image data into sections, and different workers. For example, with a canvas with image data for 1920 / 1080, I could have 8 web workers, each one would process some image data with a size of 240 / 135, but at a different offset, and the main thread would wait for all of the messages to come in, for each frame, before combining them all in the canvas with `putimageData`

Is this a good approach? Will this reduce the time on the main thread?

Comment: "50ms to send it", is it really only to send it or also to generate it? How do you generate the i.age? Does it really have to be do e on the CPU? Generate graphics is the job of the GPU normally. Also havong more workers than available cores will make all the workers and the main thread slower.

Comment: @Kaiido no nothing to do with generating it, only to literally send it there and back again, even if its completely empty, takes 50+ ms. So basically the more workers I have the slower each one goes? isthere a way to determine how many cores I Have on my omputer?

Comment: Yes upu can check navigator.maxConcurrency, always leave one for the main thread too. Bit since your problem is at sendong, havong more workers won't help. Please show your current code, you are probably doing something wrong, transferring an ImageData should take no time, even a huge one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722068/getimagedata-web-workers-how-can-i-reduce-garbage-collection/41732553#41732553

Comment: @Kaiido it should take no time at all? Im aware workers can transfer either by copying the data , or just transferring it, are you referring to the second way?

Comment: Yes, an ImageData's data should be transferred, never copied

Comment: @Kaiido Oh I guess thats the problem then, I was copying th 1920/1080 array, thats probably where the 50ms overhead is... so has anyone done this before, is it effective (not necessarily with intense 3d rendering, but basic canvas operations like recangles etc), is it practical to use canvases for this

Comment: To draw rectangles? No, the GPU is way better to do this. For fractals, yes it's being done.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the CPU work between multiple workers can indeed reduce the time needed to **generate** the image.

However, be careful to never use more workers than cores available on the machine. You can get this number by looking at the [`navigator.hardwareConcurrency`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency) . And remember to leave one of these to the main thread. Failing to do so, the concurrency of the different threads would have to be done by using task switching instead of parallelism, slowing down all affected threads...

However your problem being in sending this data between both threads, having more workers will only make the problem worse, unless we fix it:

Instead of copying the ImageData's `data`, transfer it between each thread:

*main.js*

```
const img_data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
worker.postMessage( img_data, [ img_data.data ] );
```

*worker.js*

```
onmessage = (evt) => {
  const img_data = evt.data;
  process( img_data );
  postMessage( img_data, [ img_data.data ] );
};
```

By using the second argument of `postMessage`, we transfer the ownership of the memory slot to the other thread, without having to produce any new data.

This may very well be enough for your case, but you may still want to distribute the `process` function to several Workers, if you do so, remember to work on fixed ArrayBuffers and to transfer these every time too.